# How to use a SQL where statement in delphi properly?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, pascal

I have a problem with issuing a SQL statement. I know that the English value should be a string on its own and I've tried that but it keeps throwing me one of these errors

[image]

```
 procedure TfrmPetersonGroup.btnEnglishClick(Sender: TObject);
    var
    sSqlQuery:string;
    begin
    //2.4
    dmoBandB.qryQuery.SQL.Clear;
    sSqlQuery:='DELETE FROM tblClients WHERE Nationality =' + ' English';
    dmoBandB.qryQuery.SQL.Text := sSqlQuery;
    dmoBandB.qryQuery.active := true;
    end;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could change your sSql to

```
sSqlQuery:='DELETE FROM tblClients WHERE Nationality = ' + QuotedStr('English');
```

just to get it working, but that's not the best idea, see below.

Your version of it caused the error because, without quotes around it, the Sql parser thought that `English` was an identifier, e.g. another column name like `Nationality`.

Using `QuotedStr` around column values ensures that single-quote characters embedded in the value, like

O'Brien

are escaped correctly.

The other thing is that you should replace

```
  dmoBandB.qryQuery.active := true;
```

by

```
  dmoBandB.qryQuery.ExecSql;
```

The reason is that setting Active to True is equivalent to calling .Open, which is invalid in this context because .Open only works if the Sql query returns a result set and DELETE does not (sorry, I should have noticed this problem first time around).  Once you've called ExecSql, you can reopen the table by setting qryQuery's Sql.Text to a valid SELECT statement and then calling .Open.

However, a betteer way to avoid your initial problem would be to get into the habit of using parameterised Sql statements - see http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Rio/en/Using_Parameters_in_Queries, which is applicable to all Sql DML statements (Insert, Delete, Update, Select, etc).  Apart from anything else, this may help you avoid Sql Injection exploits (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

Comment: Hi @MartynA so I replaced my sSql with yours and it's giving me a 'qryQuery: CommandText does not return a result set' error now?

Comment: Sorry, I accidentally posted while I was typing the error. I added the error in the first comment.

Comment: I would recommend using parameters instead of injecting the sql.

Comment: @Sami:  That's why I included the link, but hard-coding a complete DELETE statement is hardly "injecting" it, imo.

Answer (score 7):

I suggest you get a safe query. As below:

```
procedure SafeDeleteReq(SQLQuery: TSQLQuery; del: string);
begin
  SQLQuery.SQL.Text := 'DELETE FROM tblClients WHERE Nationality=:Nationality';
  SQLQuery.ParamByName('Nationality').AsString := del;
  SQLQuery.ExecSQL();
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  SafeDeleteReq(SQLQuery1, 'English');
end;
```

Comment: What does "del" stand for?

Comment: The SQL query's variable should have the same/similar name as the procedure's parameter name: why naming it "del" when in fact the nationality is meant? Consistency is key in programming.